# View what's killing another Windows process

Tags: windows-10, process, kill

I'm trying to figure out what (if any) process is killing another process on my Windows 10 machine.

When I boot, after logging in, explorer fails to launch and I'm met with a black screen. I can access Task Manager (through Ctrl Alt Del) and launch cmd and new processes, but not explorer. Trying `start explorer.exe` causes something to load for a sec (the mouse spins), then nothing, and no new `explorer.exe` process is created (nor were there any previously existing). There are no error messages.

My suspicion is that there could be another process (e.g. McAfee, which I seem unable to disable) killing explorer as soon as it begins. Is there any way to determine this (maybe process interactions like this are logged somewhere)?

Comment: Did you try booting in safe mode?

Comment: Seems more like damaged files. Try *SFC /scanow* and then *DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth* as Administrator.

Comment: Tried all of these - booting in same mode (no change), and running `sfc`. Couldn't even find `dism` on the machine - though I admire your Google-fu!